# base::formals with multiple-option arguments [R]

Tags: r, function, wrapper, do.call

I trying to extract all arguments and their default options from a function (`randomForestSRC::rfsrc`) to integrate it within another function. This is what I'm doing:

```
> mydata <- source("https://pastebin.com/raw/bL8ZHvbt")$value
> myparams <- list(ntree = 500, seed = 333)
> time = "OS"
> event = "Death"

# prepare vars
> aux <- formals(randomForestSRC::rfsrc)[-c(1,2,32,35)] #delete arguments I gonna manually add
> diffs <- setdiff(names(aux), names(myparams))
> method.params <- c(myparams, aux[diffs])

# run function
> f <- as.formula(paste0("Surv(", time, ",", event, ") ~ ."))
> res <- do.call(randomForestSRC::rfsrc, c(list(formula = f, data = mydata), method.params))

Error in (function (formula, data, ntree = 1000, mtry = NULL, ytry = NULL,  : 
  object 'samptype' not found
```

I guess the error prompts because `rfsrc`'s arguments format: it's not a single value but multiple options... despite of having *only one* as default option.

```
> aux$importance #default value for "importance" is "none"
c(FALSE, TRUE, "none", "permute", "random", "anti")

> str(aux)
List of 31
 $ ntree      : num 1000
 $ nodedepth  : NULL
 $ splitrule  : NULL
 $ nsplit     : num 10
 $ importance : language c(FALSE, TRUE, "none", "permute", "random", "anti")
 ...
```

My question is how can I extract this only default value and not the entire string of options? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t see a [MCVE]. SO requires one for debugging questions.

Comment: One problem is that the code of `rfsrc` expects to evaluate the ellipsis that you have removed fro the formals list. Is that removal necessary?

Comment: The other question I have is why you need to use `do.call`? Can't you just  copy `rfsrc` to a new name and work on that object by modifying the defaults and then supplying a formula and data argument? (I can get that strategy to work.)?

Comment: `do.call` is not strictly necessary, it was only a possible way. I think I don't understand you alternative... could you put some code lines, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will let you alter the defaults of the two parameters you sought to set at 500 and 333 in a new function with the same environment as the original `rfsrc`. (You can do it in the original function, but that seems more dangerous.)

```
library(randomForestSRC)
rfsrc2 <- rfsrc
environment(rfsrc2) <- environment(rfsrc)
params <- formals(rfsrc)
myparams <- list(ntree = 500, seed = 333)
params[c("ntree","seed")] <- myparams 
    # more generally could have been `params[names(myparams)]` on LHS
formals(rfsrc2) <- params

str(rfsrc2)
#-------
function (formula, data, ntree = 500, mtry = NULL, ytry = NULL, nodesize = NULL, nodedepth = NULL, splitrule = NULL, nsplit = 10, 
    importance = c(FALSE, TRUE, "none", "permute", "random", "anti"), block.size = if (any(is.element(as.character(importance), 
        c("none", "FALSE")))) NULL else 10, ensemble = c("all", "oob", "inbag"), bootstrap = c("by.root", "none", "by.user"), 
    samptype = c("swor", "swr"), samp = NULL, membership = FALSE, sampsize = if (samptype == "swor") function(x) {
        x * 0.632
    } else function(x) {
        x
    }, na.action = c("na.omit", "na.impute"), nimpute = 1, ntime, cause, proximity = FALSE, distance = FALSE, forest.wt = FALSE, 
    xvar.wt = NULL, yvar.wt = NULL, split.wt = NULL, case.wt = NULL, forest = TRUE, var.used = c(FALSE, "all.trees", "by.tree"), 
    split.depth = c(FALSE, "all.trees", "by.tree"), seed = 333, do.trace = FALSE, statistics = FALSE, ...)  

# test of "function"-ality
rfsrc2(formula=f, data=mydata)
                         Sample size: 100
                    Number of deaths: 11
                     Number of trees: 500
           Forest terminal node size: 15
       Average no. of terminal nodes: 4.464
No. of variables tried at each split: 3
              Total no. of variables: 6
       Resampling used to grow trees: swor
    Resample size used to grow trees: 63
                            Analysis: RSF
                              Family: surv
                      Splitting rule: logrank *random*
       Number of random split points: 10
                          Error rate: 58.9%
```

If you wanted to do that with do.call it could have been:

```
do.call( rfsrc2, list(formula=f, data=mydata) )
```

It's crucial that you not remove `formula`, `data` and `...` from the formals-list since they need to be there when the code in the body of the function seeks to evaluate them. I'm pretty sure you cannot just paste them back (after removing them) by using `do.call`. You could of course have side-stepped the whole process by just:

```
do.call( rfsrc, list(formula=f, data=mydata, ntree=500, seed=333) )
```

.... but I got the idea you wanted methods to do surgery on a formals-list outside of the function itself.